# Controlling Alexa Group with Smart Switch

Tags: smart-home, alexa, smart-lights

I recently installed a Gosund smart switch for my living room lights. The smart switch works great for turning on and off the outlet that's connected to the switch, and I can tell Alexa to turn it on and off. This part works great.

I also have a smart plug on a different outlet in the living room. When I say, "Alexa, turn on the living room lights," both the smart plug and the smart switch turn on. Again, this part works great.

However, I would like the smart plug to turn on and off when I press the smart switch. I cannot figure out a way to do this. They are both in the Living Room group within the Alexa app. I've looked for IFTTT integrations that would trigger the smart plug when the smart switch is pressed. This seems like it would be something that is easy and common. In fact, I thought it would just work to have the switch and the plug in the same group in the Alexa app. However, I can't find anybody online showing how to do this. Does anybody have a setup like this in Alexa without a hub? If so, how'd you set it up?

Comment: The way I see it, you'd have to make it work with just IFTTT independent of Alexa. Alexa would be just one more source of a trigger.

Comment: IFTTT doesn't have any way of seeing any of the devices, as far as I can tell. I'm not sure how IFTTT helps me at all, although it seems like it should.